# Sound control for all view

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, avaudioplayer

In my application i used back ground sounds while applications runs,i given a mute button also.For every view different sounds.Now when press the mute button the current view's player only stops .I want to mute all the players  if its muted in any of the view and plays when its clicked in any of the view.Can any one suggest me some idea

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you create a separate class for the sound effects and call it when you want to use it and then disable the class on the click of your MUTE button. Its just an idea , try it and see :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be `NSNotifications`. Post a notification when mute button is tapped and add observer on each of the view where you want play/mute sounds.

See this [NSNotificationCenter Tutorial](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2011/07/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial.html) for how to post and add observe for `NSNotification`